# Rails: rubocop disable Class has too many lines error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubocop

I have a class with constants, many constants. And rubocop is complaining about the length of this Class, which I don't care how long it gets.

I want to disable rubocop's error: "Class has too many lines" but the following is not working:

```
# rubocop:disable ClassLength
```

Also, the following isn't either:

```
# rubocop:disable Metrics/ClassLength
```

What is the correct metric that I need to disable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rubocop error 'Class definition is too long ruby'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20145230/rubocop-error-class-definition-is-too-long-ruby)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Try

```
class Xzy  # rubocop:disable Metrics/ClassLength
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working. I add it and then run rubocop but this is the response I get:

```app/constants/user_constants.rb:2:1: C: Class has too many lines. [209/100]
class UserConstants ...
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
app/constants/user_constants.rb:214:1: W: [Corrected] Unnecessary disabling of Metrics/ClassLength.
# rubocop:disable Metrics/ClassLength
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Where did you write the `disable`? Try to add it right on the class definition line. Your error message shows the warning at line 2, but the "unnecessary disabling" at line 214... something is off there.

Comment: I was putting it at the end of the file, I put it in the top and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 22):

when disabling, be sure to enable again

```
# rubocop:disable ClassLength
class LongClass
end
# rubocop:enable ClassLength
```

references:

1. [rubocop/lib/rubocop/cop/metrics/class_length.rb](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop/blob/master/lib/rubocop/cop/metrics/class_length.rb)
2. [disabling-cops-within-source-code](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/rubocop/blob/master/manual/configuration.md#disabling-cops-within-source-code)

Answer (score 18):

in `.rubocop.yml`:

```
Metrics/MethodLength:
  Max: 1000
```

Answer (score 17):

Or in `.rubocop.yml`:

```
Metrics/ClassLength:
  Exclude:
    - "path/to/your/file.rb"
```

Comment: I prefer this method over editing the Max: value in the .yml file as it is readable and easily changed for snowflake situations that do not warrant a global change. There are pros and cons to this method as compared to the answer that I provided, based on your patterns and practices.

Answer (score 4):

Using the file **.rubocop.yml** you can add this code to disable it:

```
Metrics/ClassLength:
  Enabled: false
```

You can find more information about it in the [rubocop configuration page](https://docs.rubocop.org/rubocop/0.88/configuration.html)