# Why is rubocop failing only on my branch changes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, rubocop

In our project `rubocop.yml` we have following check for number of lines in a class:

```
ClassLength:
    Max: 150 # Default 100
```

There's a file in `lib/utils/foo.rb` which is already more than 200 lines. If I run `rubocop` inspection on `master` branch then rubocop runs fine without any errors.

Now, in my `feature/cool_feature` branch I added 5 lines to this `lib/utils/foo.rb` class. Now if I run `rubocop` in my branch it fails with an following error:

```
Offenses:

lib/utils/foo.rb:1:1: C: Class has too many lines. [151/150]
```

1. Why is this file failing rubocop test when it is already having more than 150 lines in master branch? (Note: rubocop runs without any error on master branch)
2. Why the error message shows the class to have only **151** lines when this class has 214 lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`bbatsov/rubocop/lib/rubocop/cop/metrics/class_length.rb`](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop/blob/master/lib/rubocop/cop/metrics/class_length.rb#L6-L13) calls [`check_code_length(node)`](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop/blob/3c01f6923c6afa63593b0e3e4ec9d914ae8ecb5a/lib/rubocop/cop/mixin/code_length.rb#L17-L19), which calls [code_length(node)](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop/blob/ec3123fc3454b080e1100e35480c6466d1240fff/lib/rubocop/cop/mixin/classish_length.rb#L11-L19)

```
target_line_numbers = body_line_numbers -
                      line_numbers_of_inner_nodes(node, :module, :class)

target_line_numbers.reduce(0) do |length, line_number|
  source_line = processed_source[line_number]
  next length if irrelevant_line(source_line)
```

That means it will only count [relevant lines](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop/blob/3c01f6923c6afa63593b0e3e4ec9d914ae8ecb5a/lib/rubocop/cop/mixin/code_length.rb#L28) (non-empty, non-comment)

So check if the file in `master` actually has more than 150 non-empty, non-comment lines.

See "[Rubocop error 'Class definition is too long ruby'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20145230/6309)" for more.